# Algoritimo para validar CNH

Tags: ruby, validação

Olá,

Preciso validar CNH em Ruby, mas não acho nenhum código e nenhuma referência com a regra de validação. Alguém tem alguma dessas informações?

obrigado

Comment: Essa regex nao valida CNH, ela valida placa de carro

Answer (score 1):

Você pode a gem `cnh` que escrevi a algum tempo:

https://github.com/Schweigert/cnh

Ela utiliza uma API externa para validar.